# Automatically display the age in my "CREATE FORM"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model, attributes

I have birthdate and age field in my CREATE FORM and i want to automatically calculate and DISPLAY the age once the birthdate is filled in.

So I use CodeFirst of EntityFramework and MVC 3 Razor View

So here's My Model:

```
  namespace Payroll_System.Models
    {
  public class Employee
  {
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Date of Birth:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Birth Date is Required.")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0;dd/MM/yyyy}"
    , NullDisplayText = "No Date of Birth is Selected.")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }


    [Integer]
    [Min(1, ErrorMessage = "Unless you are Benjamin Button.")]
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
            int age = now.Year - BirthDate.Year;
            if (BirthDate > now.AddYears(-age)) age--; ;
            return age;
        }

    }
```

And after I created the model I create my controller with CRUD options using MVC Scaffolding. Then in the partialview of Create there is no textbox for age. So Please provide some code.

Comment: How can you expect the user to enter her age into a *read only property*? You will probably find it in a Display view, not in Create or Edit. Also, what are the `[Integer]` and `[Min]` attributes, and what is the point of validation a read only property?

Answer (score 0):

You can't enter values, and let alone validate, a **read only** property.

You may want to validate your data by implementing the [`IValidatableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx) interface.

Model:

```
public class PersonFromSO : IValidatableObject
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Date of Birth:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Birth Date is Required.")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
                   DataFormatString = "{0;dd/MM/yyyy}",
                   NullDisplayText = "No Date of Birth is Selected.")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
            int age = now.Year - BirthDate.Year;
            if (BirthDate > now.AddYears(-age)) age--; ;
            return age;
        }

    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext context)
    {
        if (Age < 1)
            yield return new ValidationResult("You were born in the future.",
                                              new[] { "Age" });
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model PersonFromSO

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BirthDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDate)

    <time>@Model.Age</time> 

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Here's also the controller I've used, if needed:

```
public class PersonFromSOController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new PersonFromSO());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PersonFromSO person)
    {
        return View(person);
    }
}
```

I would note that that is a little convoluted, and you are probably better off validating `BirthDate` directly.

Comment: this is my first MVC answer - I hope I did OK.

Answer (score -1):

```
get 
{ 
   DateTime now = DateTime.Today; 
   int age = now.Year - BirthDate.Year; 
   if (BirthDate > now.AddYears(-age)) age--; ; 
   return age; 
}
```

This is wrong if you also store the time it should be the code below

```
get 
{ 
   DateTime now = DateTime.Now; 
   int age = now.Year - BirthDate.Year; 
   if (BirthDate > now.AddYears(-age)) age--; ; 
   return age; 
}
```